# When does java.util.Date set value to cdate field?

Tags: java

I debug in my code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

While seeing the source code, I find that it just set the value to `fastTime`.

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public Date(long date) {
    fastTime = date;
}
```

There is another field `cdate` field in `java.util.Date`, but how to set value to it?

```
/*
 * If cdate is null, then fastTime indicates the time in millis.
 * If cdate.isNormalized() is true, then fastTime and cdate are in
 * synch. Otherwise, fastTime is ignored, and cdate indicates the
 * time.
 */
private transient BaseCalendar.Date cdate;
```

[![debug pic]]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2N7P.png

Comment: Your question is answered in the source code.

Comment: why do you even need to set cdate value?

Comment: @mystery I am just confused how the cdate value is from

Comment: @user207421 Can I debug in IntelliJ IDEA with breakpoint to find it out?

Comment: @Holinc Yes, you you can and you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `PrintStream.println(Object)` calls `toString()` for any object you pass into it.

Now if you look at the implementation of [`Date.toString()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Date.java#L1030) you see

```
    public String toString() {
        // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
        BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
        // format the contents of date
    }
```

You can then further look at [`Date.normalize()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Date.java#L1195) and find

```
    private final BaseCalendar.Date normalize() {
        if (cdate == null) {
            BaseCalendar cal = getCalendarSystem(fastTime);
            cdate = (BaseCalendar.Date) cal.getCalendarDate(fastTime,
                                                            TimeZone.getDefaultRef());
            return cdate;
        }
        // code to update cdate if it is already present
    }
```

Please note that a debugger that displays the current value of a variable `Date date`  also uses the `Date.toString()` method. It might therefore be difficult to trace the code path in `Date.normalize()` with `cdate == null`

Comment: I delete `System.out.println(date);` and cdate is also had a value while  I debugging.

Comment: @Holinc that is why I wrote "a debugger that displays the current value of a variable `Date date` also uses the `Date.toString()` method". Just by using a debugger to step through the code means that the `Date.toString()` method is called (how would the debugger otherwise by able produce output like `{Date@503} "Tue Apr 12 10:58:26 CST 2022"` ?) and therefor the `cdate` field is initialized.